# Cisco Packet Tracer, Invalid input detected error

Tags: router, cisco-packet-tracer

When attempting to use commands, I often get a kickback which looks like this

```
Router(config)#show ip dhcp pool
                ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

It does not matter what command it is, even "help" gives me this

```
Router(config)#help
                ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

What exactly is wrong with the second character? Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: Wow this formmated badly. The ^ symbol always shows up under the 2nd character of my commands

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly is wrong with the second character? Is there something i'm missing?

There is no command that starts with the first character followed by the second character you typed based on the access level and mode you are on.

There are [2 access levels and 5 modes](https://www.cisco.com/E-Learning/bulk/public/tac/cim/cib/using_cisco_ios_software/02_cisco_ios_hierarchy.htm) as indicated below. Some commands are not available depending on the access level and mode you are on.

> As a security feature, Cisco IOS® Software separates EXEC sessions into two different access levels: user EXEC level and privileged EXEC level. User EXEC level allows you to access only basic monitoring commands; privileged EXEC level allows you to access all router commands. Privileged EXEC level can be password protected to allow only authorized users the ability to configure or manage the router. From privileged EXEC level, you can access all the command modes. There are five command modes: global configuration mode, interface configuration mode, subinterface configuration mode, router configuration mode, and line configuration mode.

Based on the extract you have shown (`Router(config)#show ip dhcp pool`), you are on configuration mode. The `show` command in not available in that mode. To access it, it must be preceded by the `do` command like:

```
Router(config)#do show ip dhcp pool
```

> It does not matter what command it is, even "help" gives me this

To get help, you must type `?`. The question mark is the help command not `help`.